# Nested IIF Statements with Switches Error

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

I have the following statement in one of my tablix fields and am just receiving #error when rendering the report.  I am not sure the exact issue, but if anyone could possible point me in the right direction it would be helpful;

```
=IIF(Fields!inflowType.Value="1",
    Switch(
          Fields!inflowTaxTreatment.Value = "0","Amount is Pre-Tax",     
          Fields!inflowTaxTreatment.Value = "1","Amount is Post-Tax/Not Taxed") ,Nothing) 
Or 
IIF(Fields!inflowType.Value = "3",
    Switch(
         Fields!inflowTaxTreatment.Value = "0","Tax Deferred",
         Fields!inflowTaxTreatment.Value="1","Tax Free"),Nothing) 
Or 
IIF(Fields!inflowType.Value="0",
    Switch(
         Fields!inflowTaxTreatment.Value="0","0% Taxable",
         Fields!inflowTaxTreatment.Value="1","50% Taxable",
         Fields!inflowTaxTreatment.Value="2","85% Taxable"),Nothing)
```

Basically I didn't know if i could use nested switch statements to achieve the same thing, i saw this as a suggestion on another thread that was accepted, but it is/does not work for me.

Comment: It doesn't work because you are not using correctly OR operator. you have IIF() OR IIF () OR IIF() the or operator only works in the predicate expression inside the IIF, `IIF(this OR this, do this, IIF(this or this, do this, do that))`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, that's actually what I had at first, and i get the error of no expression accepts that many arguments so I looked for an alternative method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=IIF(Fields!inflowType.Value="1",
    Switch(
          Fields!inflowTaxTreatment.Value = "0","Amount is Pre-Tax",     
          Fields!inflowTaxTreatment.Value = "1","Amount is Post-Tax/Not Taxed") ,  
IIF(Fields!inflowType.Value = "3",
    Switch(
         Fields!inflowTaxTreatment.Value = "0","Tax Deferred",
         Fields!inflowTaxTreatment.Value="1","Tax Free")
,
IIF(Fields!inflowType.Value="0",
    Switch(
         Fields!inflowTaxTreatment.Value="0","0% Taxable",
         Fields!inflowTaxTreatment.Value="1","50% Taxable",
         Fields!inflowTaxTreatment.Value="2","85% Taxable"),Nothing)
))
```

I am not sure but I think this what you are trying to get, let me know if this helps you.

Comment: that worked perfectly, thank you for your help! so i was basically treating each IIF as a singular statement rather than one large one with nested iifs in it, i appreciate your help! perfect

Comment: You are welcome, if you are not expecting a better answer you can select my answer as correct to notify community your question was correctly answered. [How to select an answer as correct](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)